# I'm trying to nest an if statement within a let, but I can't get the let to accept the else statement

Tags: functional-programming, scheme

```
(let ((cmd (car linelist))
      (lineitem(if (> (length linelist) 1)
                (cdr linelist)
                ( '("test"))
                             ))))
```

This is just a small part of my code, don't worry about any of the variables, everything works fine except this:

I can't get lineitem to ever equal "test." While the if statement is true, everything works fine. But if the if statement is ever false I get this:

```
 expected a procedure that can be applied to arguments
  given: "test"
  arguments...: [none]
  context...:
```

I'm pretty confused because I think I have everything right.

Comment: I don't see any `stmt` in your code, which might be why it is never equal to `"test"`

Comment: I knew I screwed something up, "lineitem" is what I am trying to get to be "test." Sorry

Comment: Completely beside the point, but `length` is potentially very expensive and Scheme programmers usually prefer `(not (null? (cdr ls)))` to `(> (length ls) 1)`. (`(not (empty? (rest ls)))` if you're being modern.)

Comment: You know, my instructor mentioned this as well. I'll keep it in mind, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is saying that you are trying to use `"test"` as a function, which it thinks you are because you surrounded it with `()`.  It isn't clear what you are actually trying to accomplish there, so I can't say how it should be fixed.